# Algorithm - how many times biggest number appeared in collection

Tags: c++, algorithm

I have a struggle with my c++ homework.

I have a table a[]{2,3,4,2,7,4,7,2}

The task is to find lowest, biggest number and how many times they have appeared (I can do that in only one iteration).

So far I've managed to find lowest, biggest and how many times lowest has appeared.

**I can't figure out an algorithm to find how many times the biggest has appeared.**

I was thinking about sorting, but seems to complicated..

This is my code so far (yea I know that using namespace std is wrong).

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>

using namespace std;

void minMaxRep(
    int a[],
    size_t size,
    int& mn,
    int& mx,
    size_t& in,
    size_t& ix);

int main()
{

    int a[]{ 2,3,4,2,7,4,7,2 };
    size_t size = sizeof(a) / sizeof(*a);
    int mn, mx; 
    size_t in, ix;

    minMaxRep(a, size, mn, mx, in, ix);

    cout << "Array: [ ";
    for (size_t i = 0; i < size; ++i)
        cout << a[i] << " ";
    cout << "]\n";
    cout << "Min = " << mn << " " << in << " times\n";
    cout << "Max = " << mx << " " << ix << " times\n";

}

void minMaxRep(int a[], size_t size, int& mn, int& mx, size_t& in, size_t& ix) {

    int lowestNumber= *a, biggestNumber= *a, timesMin= 0, timesBig= 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        if (a[i] <= lowestNumber) {
            lowestNumber= a[i];
            timesMin++;
        }
        else if (a[i] >= biggestNumber) {
            biggestNumber= a[i];
        }
    }

    mn = lowestNumber;
    mx = biggestNumber;
    in = timesMin;
    ix = timesBig;

};
```

Appriciate any help :)

Comment: Two things 1) Counting how many times one particular number occurs would be exactly the same as counting how many times a different number occurs. If you're counting the smallest number correctly, the same approach should work exactly the same. 2) you're not counting the smallest number correctly. If the input array is [4,3,2,1], your algorithm will conclude that the lowest number is 1, and that it occured 4 times. That's obviously broken. Fix your broken algorithm first, then simply use it to count the highest number, in exactly the same way.

Comment: You need separate checks for `<` (reset `leastcount=1` and set new least) and then an `=` (increment `leastcount++`). You would do the same for most.

Comment: Your `timesMin` is wrong.  Given '3, 2, 1' as input, it will claim the lowest is 1 - seen three times.  You need `if (a[i] < lowestNumber) { lowest = a[i]; timeMin = 1; } else if (a[i] == lowestNumber) {timeMin++;}`,  The comparison with 'bigest' should be a separate 'if', not an 'else if'.  (If the the input is 1 1 1 1, then you want to output that that lowest number is 1, seen 4 times, and that the highest number is one seen 4 times.)

Comment: Wow, thank for the quick answer :)

Comment: It helped me a lot, now I understand.

Answer (score 3):

To find the biggest number and how many times it appears you could iterate through a[] and do two things each time.

1. Check to see if a[i] > biggestNumber, if it is update biggestNumber = a[i] and set timesBig = 0
2. Check if a[i] == biggestNumber, if it is timesBig++;

   ```
   for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
       if (a[i]  > biggestNumber) {
           biggestNumber = a[i];
           timesBig = 0;
       }
       if (a[i] == biggestNumber) {
           timesBig++;
       }
   }
   ```

   You could also use the same logic for the smallest number.